# script "By wifi or by Ethernet"

Tags: scripting, wifi, ethernet

I have a host who can be connected by wifi or by ethernet.
According to the link I want to make actions.

How to detect that with a script ?

Comment: You should tell **in your question** what type and version of OS you have. I also suggest to explain some background: What actions do you want to perform depending on the network link? For what purpose?  Do you want to run the script at any time to check the current network link or do you want to run it when the connection is established? ...

Comment: English sense making not. Question edit clearer make.

Comment: Most recent distros have hooks in their network config *specifically* for users to drop custom scripts into. In debian that's `/etc/network/if-up.d/`; Check with your distro's documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface used for each type of link is different. Say, the ethernet interface could be *eth0* and the WLAN interface could be *wlan0*. Knowing the names you could find which is active and act accordingly.

To list all interface and show their status use the command `ip link show`. This command works in the modern flavors of Linux, and so the rest of the utils and Bash shell. I suppose you could adapt it to any OS (In Windows, I suggest using cygwin and *awk* or Python to parse the *ipconfig* or *netsh* output, or [PowerShell Get-NetAdapter module](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/using-powershell-to-find-connected-network-adapters/)).

Example output:

```
user@host$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group     default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens32: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:9b:90:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

You could then filter the interface name/status using `grep` looking for lines starting with a number:

```
user@host$ ip link show | grep "^[0-9]"
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group     default qlen 1
2: ens32: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
```

The active interfaces have the word UP, so to get the active one filter out the local interface localhost (*lo:*):

```
user@host$ ip link show | grep "^[0-9]" | grep -v "lo: " | grep "UP"
2: ens32: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
```

We need only the interface name, the second word:

```
user@host$ ip link show | grep "^[0-9]" | grep -v "lo: " | grep "UP" | cut -d ':' -f 2
 ens32
```

You could store this result in some variable (in Bash):

```
ACTIVEIF=$(ip link show | grep "^[0-9]" | grep -v "lo: " | grep "UP" | cut -d ':' -f 2)
```

Of course, if you have more than one active interface store the list in an array of names adding parenthesis and spaces around the result. For example (**from now on, I won't filter lo:, as I only have one physical interface**):

```
ACTIVEIFACES=( $(ip link show | grep "^[0-9]" | grep "UP" | cut -d ':' -f 2) )
```

To check the array variable contents:

```
user@host$ set | grep ^ACTIVEIFACES
ACTIVEIFACES=([0]="lo" [1]="ens32")
```

and to list them in a script:

```
ACTIVEIFACES=( $(ip link show | grep "^[0-9]" | grep "UP" | cut -d ':' -f 2) )
NIFACES=${#ACTIVEIFACES[@]}
if [ $NIFACES -ne 0 ] ; then
   echo "There exist $NIFACES active interfaces:"
   for ((i=0; i<NIFACES; i++)) ; do
       echo "${ACTIVEIFACES[$i]}"
   done
else
   echo "There is no active interfaces detected"
fi
```

(As the `for` command uses numeric expressions, you could omit the $ in $i and $NIFACES between the double parentheses).

The script output in my case is:

```
There exist 2 active interfaces:
lo
ens32
```

I hope this method is useful to you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The naive answer would be to monitor the interfaces, but a layer-2 interface will register as "up" when it's plugged in (ethernet) or associated (wifi), but that on its own does not tell you whether it will be used to carry traffic.

It may be more effective to monitor for changes to the default route(s) instead.

The `ip mon` command can be used to track changes, though it also gives regular status updates even when nothing appears to have changed, so you need to be prepared to ignore those.

(Using the `-o` option is recommended, so that each report comes on one line; that makes parsing a lot simpler.)

```
#!/bin/bash
ip -o mon |
sed -e 's/\\/ /g
        s/  */ /g
        s/^\(Deleted \|\)\([0-9]*\): \([^ :]*\) /\1addr \2 \3 / 
        s/^\(Deleted \|\)\([0-9]*\): \([^ :]*\): /\1link \2 \3 / ' |
while
    IFS=' ' read -ra line
do
    if [[ ${line[0]} = Deleted ]]
    then
        mode=delete
        line=( "${line[@]:1}" )  # shift(line)
    else
        mode=update
    fi
    case "${line[*]}" in
        addr)  # added by 'sed' above
            device_num=${line[1]}
            device_name=${line[2]}
            family=${line[3]}  # 'inet' or 'inet6'
            ip_address=${line[4]}
            # ... handle address changes  ...
            ;;
        link)  # added by 'sed' above
            device_num=${line[1]}
            device_name=${line[2]%:}
            state=${line[3]}   # eg '<BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>'
            # ... handle link UP/DOWN ...
            ;;
        default)
            # ... handle default route changes ...
            ;;
        prefix | local | broadcast | multicast | throw | unreachable | prohibit | blackhole )
            # ... handle other route changes ...
            ;;
    esac
done
```